# jQuery - Run keyup function on all items

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code takes a youtube url and gets the thumbnail of the link and shortens it. The problem is that when I try to change the code to work for each instance of the input and not just the one instance as it's linked to the ID:

Currently only working on the input with the id:

`var elemOutput = document.getElementById("thumb_video");`

Tried to change to classname in order for it to work on each instance:

`var elemOutput = document.getElementsByClassName("video__thumb");`

How do I get the code to run on each instance of the `input`?

```js
/**
 * Get YouTube ID from various YouTube URL
 * @author: takien
 * @link https://gist.github.com/takien/4077195
 */

function YouTubeGetID(url) {
  var ID = "";
  url = url
    .replace(/(>|<)/gi, "")
    .split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
  if (url[2] !== undefined) {
    ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);
    ID = ID[0];
  } else {
    ID = url;
  }
  return ID;
}

/**
 *
 */
function getPosterUrl(url) {
  var posterUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{videoID}/maxresdefault.jpg";
  var videoID = YouTubeGetID(url);

  posterUrl = posterUrl.replace(/{videoID}/g, videoID);

  return posterUrl;
}

function setPosterUrl(url) {
  var videoID, posterUrl, elemContainer, elemAnker, elemImg;
  var images = [
    /*"maxresdefault.jpg",
    "sddefault.jpg",
    "hqdefault.jpg",
    "mqdefault.jpg",*/
    "default.jpg"
  ];

  videoID = YouTubeGetID(url);

  var elemOutput = document.getElementById("thumb_video");

  elemOutput.innerHTML = "";

  images.forEach(function(item, index) {
    elemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    elemAnker = document.createElement("a");
    elemImg = document.createElement("img");

    posterUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoID + "/" + images[index];

    elemAnker.href = posterUrl;
    elemAnker.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    elemAnker.setAttribute("rel", "noopener");

    elemImg.src = posterUrl;
    elemImg.setAttribute("alt", "");

    elemAnker.appendChild(elemImg);
    elemContainer.appendChild(elemAnker);
    elemOutput.appendChild(elemContainer);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $input = $(".video__input");
  var $icon = $(".video__icon");
  var valLength;

  $input.on("keyup", function(e) {
    var newval = "",
      $this = $(this);

    if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/))) {
      $this.val(newval.pop());
    } else if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\.be\/)+([^\/]+)/))) {
      $this.val(newval.pop());
    } else if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\embed\/)+([^\/]+)/))) {
      $this.val(newval.pop().replace("?rel=0", ""));
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    setPosterUrl($input.val());
    $icon.hide();
  });

  $input.on("input", function() {
    valLength = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input class="video__input" type="text" placeholder="Video URL">
  <div class="video__thumb" id="thumb_video"></div>
  <div class="video__icon">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input class="video__input" type="text" placeholder="Video URL">
  <div class="video__thumb" id=""></div>
  <div class="video__icon">Test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. you have to iterate over all the items you have to somehow know which belong together. (see the code)
   `var $items = $(".item"); $items.each(function(){ var $input = $(this).children(".video__input"); // .... and more`
2. inside the `setPosterUrl()` function you just picked another element with ID out of nowhere so then you just overwrite it. Now it's changed so you can pass the element (a plain javascript element) to the function which is you image placeholder...

```js
/**
 * Get YouTube ID from various YouTube URL
 * @author: takien
 * @link https://gist.github.com/takien/4077195
 */

function YouTubeGetID(url) {
  var ID = "";
  url = url
    .replace(/(>|<)/gi, "")
    .split(/(vi\/|v=|\/v\/|youtu\.be\/|\/embed\/)/);
  if (url[2] !== undefined) {
    ID = url[2].split(/[^0-9a-z_\-]/i);
    ID = ID[0];
  } else {
    ID = url;
  }
  return ID;
}

/**
 *
 */
function getPosterUrl(url) {
  var posterUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/{videoID}/maxresdefault.jpg";
  var videoID = YouTubeGetID(url);

  posterUrl = posterUrl.replace(/{videoID}/g, videoID);

  return posterUrl;
}

function setPosterUrl(onThisElement, url) {
  var videoID, posterUrl, elemContainer, elemAnker, elemImg;
  var images = [
    /*"maxresdefault.jpg",
    "sddefault.jpg",
    "hqdefault.jpg",
    "mqdefault.jpg",*/
    "default.jpg"
  ];

  videoID = YouTubeGetID(url);

  var elemOutput = onThisElement;

  elemOutput.innerHTML = "";

  images.forEach(function(item, index) {
    elemContainer = document.createElement("div");
    elemAnker = document.createElement("a");
    elemImg = document.createElement("img");

    posterUrl = "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + videoID + "/" + images[index];

    elemAnker.href = posterUrl;
    elemAnker.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
    elemAnker.setAttribute("rel", "noopener");

    elemImg.src = posterUrl;
    elemImg.setAttribute("alt", "");

    elemAnker.appendChild(elemImg);
    elemContainer.appendChild(elemAnker);
    elemOutput.appendChild(elemContainer);
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  var $items = $(".item");

  $items.each(function(){
    var $input = $(this).children(".video__input");
    var $icon = $(this).children(".video__icon");
    var valLength;
  
    $input.on("keyup", function(e) {
      var newval = "",
      $this = $(this);

      if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\?|&)v=([^&#]+)/))) {
        $this.val(newval.pop());
      } else if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\.be\/)+([^\/]+)/))) {
        $this.val(newval.pop());
      } else if ((newval = $this.val().match(/(\embed\/)+([^\/]+)/))) {
        $this.val(newval.pop().replace("?rel=0", ""));
      }
      e.preventDefault();
      setPosterUrl($icon[0], $input.val()); // $icon[0] the "[0]" part is only to convert from jQuery element to plain javascript element!
      $icon.hide();
    });

    $input.on("input", function() {
      valLength = $.trim($(this).val()).length;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input class="video__input" type="text" placeholder="Video URL">
  <div class="video__thumb" id="thumb_video"></div>
  <div class="video__icon">Test</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <input class="video__input" type="text" placeholder="Video URL">
  <div class="video__thumb" id=""></div>
  <div class="video__icon">Test</div>
</div>
```